# Deriving 68% confidence level for each parameter after MCMC

Tags: probability-or-statistics, markov-chains

I used the MCMC package https://github.com/joshburkart/mathematica-mcmc to find the best parameters for model of Massive Gravity. Now I need to find the confidence 68% for each of those parameters and have no idea how to proceed. This is my first time doing anything like this. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.1613v1.pdf I'm trying to reproduce the confidence levels in this paper which are in results section. Any help will be much appreciated. The current output of my MCMC
[image: The current output of my MCMC]

The current output of my MCMC
MCMC[(1.725`- RR[M, W, w, h, m, 1091.3`])) (-1/2), {{M, .28, .001, 
Real}, {w, -1, .001, Real}, {W, 0, .001, Real}, {h, .7, .001, 
Real}, {m, .135, .001, Real}}, 39000]

```
"MCMCResult"[{M -> 0.292338, w -> -1.03469, W -> 0.0506029,h -> 0.680667,m -> 0.140849}, "\[LeftSkeleton]39000\[RightSkeleton]"]

"ParameterErrors" -> {M -> 0.0136284, w -> 0.0564952, W -> 0.0418342,
```

h -> 0.0131136, m -> 0.00542007}, "AverageAcceptance" -> 0.789823, "TimeSpent" -> 149855.631056 Second, "NumSteps" -> 39000, "Parameters" -> {M, w, W, h, m}, "ProposalSpreads" -> {0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001}, "ParameterDomains" -> {Real, Real, Real, Real,  Real}, "BurnFraction" -> 0.1, "BurnEnd" -> 3900

Comment: If you include your code you used to estimate the parameters (or at least a minimal working example), you'll likely get better and quicker help.

Comment: I added more to my question.

Comment: I'm asking how I would be able to get the 68% confidence interval for my parameters. This is the info that I know.

Comment: Please add code as text, not (only)  as image. You need to add all necessary input to reproduce your resuts, otherwise this question will be closed.

Comment: Alright I will try to post the code.

Comment: If the result of executing the MCMC function is labeled mcmc, then you want to look at the simulations stored in `mcmc["ParameterRun"]`.  I think you'll need to remove the first 3900 observations as all simulations including the burn-in values seem to be store in `mcmc["ParameterRun"]`.  From those observations you can estimate credible intervals.

Comment: Alright I was able to do that. From there does it become just a matter of finding the standard deviation and using the formulas learned in elementary stat class to find the 68% confidence interval?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is an extended comment rather than an answer.**

Without the definition of the function `RR`, one can't give you very specific advice.

However, if the output of `MCMC` is placed in `mcmc`, then you can get a list of all of the MCMC runs for all of the parameters using

```
results = mcmc["ParameterRun"];
```

This array will include all of the burn-in values.  By looking at the code and trying a few other examples it appears that the runs that you want to keep are given by the following:

```
numsteps = 3900 (* The number of runs you requested *)
k = Min[1000, Floor[nnumsteps/2]];
results = mcmc["ParameterRun"][[k;;]]
```

From `results` you can duplicate `mcmc["BestFitParameters"]` and `mcmc["ParameterErrors"]`:

```
mcmc["BestFitParameters"]
{Mean[results[[All, 1]]], Mean[results[[All, 2]]]}

mcmc["ParameterErrors"]
{StandardDeviation[results[[All, 1]]], StandardDeviation[results[[All, 2]]]}
```

If you are able to assume (rather than just willing to assume) that the resulting distributions are normal, then parameter estimates plus-or-minus the associated standard deviation gets the "68% confidence intervals".  (If you're really making Bayesian inferences, you should really call these "credible intervals" and explicitly state your prior distributions.)

If you can't assume normal distributions, then one can use the `Quantile` function to get the intervals:

```
Table[{Quantile[results[[All, i]], (100 - 68)/200], 
  Quantile[results[[All, i]], 1 - (100 - 68)/200]}, {i, Dimensions[results][[2]]}]
```

This finds the middle 68% of the results for each parameter.

Comment: this last expression gives you an interval at whose extrema the distribution takes different values. How would you find the so-called "Highest Density Interval"?